# Iterate over an ArrayList of more than 5000 object instances

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am using `JDK5`, operating system as Windows7, ram size of 6gb and dual core processor

I have an array list which having 5000 records and its size can increase eventually.

As it this ArrayList can contain huge amount of data, so will it be a good approach if i divide the list in to two parts and with the help of FututreTask, of java concurrent package, spawn two threads T1 and T2, so that the threads (T1 and T2) can iterate over this ArrayList in parallel and finish it much faster.

Kindly provide a suggestion as i am not able to come to a conclusion on implementing the FutureTask for iterating over an Arraylist.

Comment: increase to what? 5000 objects isn't a whole lot (depending on the object of course). 50000 objects still isn't a whole lot (still depending on the object). You need to be more specific about what you are going to be dealing with before people can give you architectural advice on how to cope with it.

Comment: A `BlockingDeque` can be a simple yet effective approach to implement a multi-threaded workers pattern in java. Each thread just reads an item of work from the queue when it is ready and processes it.

Comment: There is no specific limit, i mean i am fetching records from the database which returns large amount of data and storing it in the Arraylist. Now when i try to iterate through this list it is taking more than 10 secs as it is returning many fields.

Comment: It's a shame you can't use JDK8, this is exactly what the stream API was designed for. In fact, http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/ this could help?

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to jump into multithreading, and you should not do so unless you understand how it will help you.  In the above scenario there's probably not much to be gained.  More useful when you have a lot of communications or "disk" I/O do do.

Comment: I think we need example code to see what you are currently doing, but please keep the example code short enough to read yet specific enough to show what you are doing when you iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As read in your comment, are you using a persistent API like Hibernate to get the list from database? If no, then iterating the ResultSet and storing it in list is clearly an overhead as you need to iterate it later.

Coming to the actual question, you can split the list into two and use threads but there will be some cons depending on what operation you're performing. If you're doing some operations on the list while iteration like writing it to file, your order of the list will be lost.

Comment: Thanks,Yes i am using Hibernate to retrieve data from the database which can return a large amount of data. I am not doing any I/O operation other then populating another list so that it can used in the frontend for list the values in the GUI.

Comment: You can use the same list which you got from database in the front end if this agrees with your design pattern. As using an additional thread is not much of a help here, you have to look at minor overheads and eliminate them. If you are populating a different type of list say List<A> from your List<B>, then there is no alternative to looping.

Answer (score 1):

I write this answer assuming you are using a single CPU to execute your program. Just use a single for loop. Use threads when you can interleave CPU tasks with I/O tasks or interleave multiple I/O tasks. The advantage of threads in these cases is that when one is idle (e.g. synchronous I/O calls such as file read), the other (say your CPU task) can take over.

If you use threads in your case, the CPU has to spend additional time in thread switching.

Comment: Thanks.. I agree but is there any alternative, i just want to know a faster approach over iterating a list.

Comment: The short answer is no... Visiting each item of a list of size n is of the order of Omega(n)... that is you have to visit every element anyway... The long answer is yes only if you have multiple computing resources only in cases when these visits to the sub-arrays are independent of each other....

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use more threads so that you can accomplish the task faster.

Comment: Thanks so i think i can make use of Future Task and complete the task.

Comment: Not if you have only one processor though... Threads are useful when you want to interleave CPU processing with I/O processing... it's of not much of a use (read actually slower) when you use threads for interleaving two (or more) CPU processing tasks...